# Passing a Lambda Expression to std::function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm currently struggling with lambda expressions.
I created a ConcurrentDictionary which wraps std::map with a mutex.
Now I'd like to export all elements that match a specified condition.

```
template<typename MutexTypeT, typename Key_Type_T, typename Mapped_Type_T>
class CConcurrentDictionary
{
    public:
        ///Constructor
        CConcurrentDictionary();

        class CSingleElement
        {
        public:

          ///the key
          Key_Type_T key = { };

          ///THe Mapped Type
          Mapped_Type_T mapped_type = { };

        };

     template<typename ...Args_T>
        std::vector<CSingleElement> exportSelectedData(
            const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout,
            std::function<bool(const CSingleElement, Args_T &&...)> compareFn,
            Args_T&&...CompareArgs...) const;

}

template<typename MutexTypeT, typename Key_Type_T, typename Mapped_Type_T>
   template<typename ...Args_T>
   auto CConcurrentDictionary<MutexTypeT, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::exportSelectedData(
          const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout,
          std::function<bool(const CSingleElement, Args_T &&...)> compareFn,
          Args_T&&...CompareArgs...) const ->
      std::vector<CSingleElement>
      {
        //lock mutex...
        std::vector<CSingleElement> vecRes;
        for (const auto &single_element : dictionary)
        {
          if(compareFn(single_element, CompareArgs...))
          {
            //this element mathes the preconditions
            vecRes.push_back(single_element);
          }
        }

        return vecRes;
      }
```

However when I try to use this class like this

```
 class CTraceCmdDuration
  {

  public:


    ///Cmd Datatype
    using CmdType_T = uint32_t;

    class CCmdSummary
    {
    public:
      /**
       * SIngle Long Running Cmd Summary
       * @param CmdIdArg Cmd ID
       * @param u32MaxCmdDurationArg Max CmdDuration
       */
      CCmdSummary(const CmdType_T CmdIdArg, const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDurationArg);
      ///Id of this cmd
      const CmdType_T CmdId;

      ///Duration of this cmd
      const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDuration;
    };

/**
     * Exports all Cmds to a vector with took longer than u32MaxCmdDuration
     * @param u32MaxCmdDuration Maximal Cmd Processing duration time. Cmds that took longer than this will be exported
     * @param u32MutexTimeout Mutex Timeout
     * @return List with all long running cmds
     */
    std::vector<CCmdSummary> ExportLongRunningCmds(const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDuration, const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout) const;

}

  auto CTraceCmdDuration::ExportLongRunningCmds(const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDuration, const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout) const ->
      std::vector<CCmdSummary>
  {
    auto lambda = [u32MaxCmdDuration](const CombinedDictElement& singleElement)
        {
          const bool bRes = (u32MaxCmdDuration < singleElement.mapped_type.u32MaxProcessingDuration);
          return bRes;
        };
    auto vecRes = dict.exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda, u32MaxCmdDuration);
    return vecRes;
  }
```

This unfortunately produces no matching call to function errors

```
error: no matching function for call to 'NConcurrent_Container::CConcurrentDictionary<NMutex::CEmbos_Mutex, long unsigned int, NDebug::CTraceCmdDuration::CProcessingInfo>::exportSelectedData(const uint32_t&, NDebug::CTraceCmdDuration::ExportLongRunningCmds(uint32_t, uint32_t) const::__lambda0&, const uint32_t&) const'
     auto vecRes = dict.exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda, u32MaxCmdDuration);
```

What is wrong with my lambda expression?
The Idea was to pass the max allowed time duration as a capture and every single stored element in the std::map as an argument.

Or do you have a better Idea?
Could you help me out here?

**Edit**: 
Thx for your answer this works well if I pass a static function
but how would I pass the lambda as a template argument?

```
static bool CompareDuaration(const CSingleElement&singleElement, const uint32_t u32MaxDuration);

  auto CTraceCmdDuration::ExportLongRunningCmds(const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDuration, const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout) const ->
      std::vector<CombinedDictElement>
  {
    auto vecRes = dict.exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda, u32MaxCmdDuration);
    return vecRes;
  }
```

This works but

```
auto CTraceCmdDuration::ExportLongRunningCmds(const uint32_t u32MaxCmdDuration, const uint32_t u32MutexTimeout) const ->
      std::vector<CombinedDictElement>
  {

    auto lambda = [u32MaxCmdDuration](const CombinedDictElement& singleElement)
        {
          const bool bRes = (u32MaxCmdDuration < singleElement.mapped_type.u32MaxProcessingDuration);
          return bRes;
        };

    auto vecRes = dict.exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda, u32MaxCmdDuration);
    return vecRes;
  }
```

gives me a compile error

```
error: no match for call to '(CTraceCmdDuration::ExportLongRunningCmds(uint32_t, uint32_t) const::__lambda0) (CConcurrentDictionary<NMutex::CEmbos_Mutex, long unsigned int, CTraceCmdDuration::CProcessingInfo>::CSingleElement&, const long unsigned int&)'
       if(compareFn(singleElement, compareArgs...))
```

It seams like passing lambdas to templates does not work so well. What am I Missing?

Comment: What is a `CombinedDictElement`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

The problem you have can be reduced to this:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(std::function<bool(Args...)>) { }

int main()
{
    foo([](int, int) { return true; });
}
```

which will fail to compile. The reason for this is that the type deduction for the template arguments for `std::function` fails.

You expect a `std::function` of some sort to be passed as an argument. Since no `std::function` object (of whatever exact instantiation) is passed in, the compiler tries to construct a `std::function` and deduce the template parameter types by calling the constructor of `std::function`. Here starts the problem. The matching constructor in this case would be:

```
template <typename F>
function(F f);
```

You will notice that **the constructor itself** is also templated. The compiler could successfully deduce `F` as a lambda, but since `F` is a template parameter of the constructor, the template parameter of the class itself `std::function` cannot be deduced.

Furthermore, to quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) on that constructor:

> [...] This constructor does not participate in overload resolution
>   unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R. [...]

This means that the existance of this constructor is based on whether `F` can be called with the class template arguments `Args...`, but since those are not explicitly defined and cannot be deduced, this constructor won't be available anyway.

## The solution

Since you only use that `std::function` inside `exportSelectedData`, simply make it a template parameter alltogether (ditching the `std::function` part):

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args_T>
std::vector<CSingleElement> exportSelectedData(uint32_t u32MutexTimeout, Func compareFn, Args_T const&...) const;
```

You should also change `Args_T&&` to `Args_T const&` since you don't simply forward those arguments but reuse them inside a loop.

### Edit

Regarding your follow-up question in the edit: think about what you're doing.

First you declare a lambda:

```
auto lambda = [u32MaxCmdDuration](const CombinedDictElement& singleElement) { /* ... */ };
```

Now think about the signature of that lambda. You return a boolean so the return type is `bool` (so far so good). You take `u32MaxCmdDuration` in the **capture-clause** and you take one argument `singleElement`. Lets remove all the *extra* qualifiers and look at the signature:

```
bool(CombinedDictElement) // take a CombinedDictElement and return a bool
```

Next, we take a look at the call of `exportSelectedData`:

```
exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda, u32MaxCmdDuration);
```

You pass in `u32MutexTimeout` and `lambda` which is perfectly fine, the lambda is captued by `compareFn`. The third argument is `u32MaxCmdDuration` which is captured by `...compareArgs` in your template. Now lets take a look at where you actually invoke the lambda inside `exportSelectedData`:

```
if (compareFn(singleElement, compareArgs...)) // ...
```

What signature do you expect `compareFn` to have here? If we expand the `...compareArgs` pack (again, removing the *extra* qualifiers for simplicity) the signature looks like this:

```
bool(CombinedDictElement, unsigned int) // take a CombinedDictElement and an unsigned int and return a bool
```

Here is the lambda signature again:

```
bool(CombinedDictElement)
```

Do you spot the problem? The lambda captures `u32MaxCmdDuration` as a state capture while `exportSelectedData` expects it as an parameter (since you passed it into `exportSelectedData` as an additional argument). The signatures differ from each other, obviously, so we have to change one of them to match the other. This is fairly easy in your case, either

- change your lambda to take `u32MaxCmdDuration` as a parameter:

  ```
  auto lambda = [](const CombinedDictElement& singleElement, unsigned int u32MaxCmdDuration)
  ```

  or
- remove `u32MaxCmdDuration` as an additional argument to your `exportSelectedData` call:

  ```
   exportSelectedData(u32MutexTimeout, lambda);
  ```

Comment: hey thx for your reply :) This worked well for a normal function. But passing a lambda still causes some errors. Could you help me out here? I edited my question accordingly :)